# What is the fundamental difference between tar (Unix) and tarfile (Python)?

Tags: python, tar, tarfile

What is the fundamental difference between tarring a folder using `tar` on Unix and `tarfile` in Python that results in a different file size?

In the example below, there is an 8.2 MB difference.  I'm currently using a Mac.  The folder in this example contains a bunch of random text files for testing purposes.

`tar -cvf archive_unix.tar files/`

`python -m tarfile -c archive_pycli.tar files/ # using Python 3.9.6`

```
-rw-r--r--  1 userid  staff  24606720 Oct 15 09:40 archive_pycli.tar
-rw-r--r--  1 userid  staff  16397824 Oct 15 09:39 archive_unix.tar
```

Comment: The first step would be to run `tar -tvf` on both archives to see what differences might exist between their contents.

Comment: I have already done this and both are identical.  I created two files containing the contents of each file, and then compared those contents.  The same number of files exist and all of the file sizes are identical.

Comment: The one possibility that comes to mind is that you're dealing with *sparse files* - files with sufficiently long runs of null bytes that entire disk blocks can be omitted from their storage.  Some `tar` implementations preserve sparseness, some don't.  However, that's not compatible with your description of these as "random text files", since a text file shouldn't contain null bytes at all.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Interesting question.  The documentation of `tarfile`
(https://docs.python.org/3/library/tarfile.html) mentions that the
default format for tar archive created by `tarfile` is, since python
3.8, `PAX_FORMAT` whereas archives created by the `tar` command have
the GNU format which I believe explains the difference.

Now to produce the same archive as the `tar` command and one with the
default format (as your command did):

```py
import tarfile
with tarfile.TarFile(name='archive-py-gnu.tar', mode='w', format=tarfile.GNU_FORMAT) as tf:
    tf.add('tmp')
with tarfile.TarFile(name='archive-py-default.tar', mode='w') as tf:
    tf.add('tmp')
```

For comparison:

```
$ tar cf archive-tar.tar tmp/
$ ls -l 
3430400 16:28 archive-py-default.tar
3317760 16:28 archive-py-gnu.tar
3317760 16:27 archive-tar.tar
```

Results of the `file` command:

```
$ file archive_unix.tar
archive_unix.tar: POSIX tar archive (GNU)
$ file archive-py-gnu.tar
archive-py-gnu.tar: POSIX tar archive (GNU)
$ file archive-py-default.tar
archive-py-default.tar: POSIX tar archive
```

Now I cannot tell you the difference between the different formats,
sorry.  But I hope this helps.

Comment: I appreciate you taking the time to help me out.  Your answer lead me to finding out you can change the file format when using ```tar```, so I gave that a try and was able to confirm the size difference was due to different archive formats.

Comment: @Simon1 Glad I could help.  I often use `tarfile` but never noticed this behaviour so your question interested me.