# Large size of the tar files generated by python tarfile

Tags: linux, shell, tar, webdataset

Aftering generating some tar files using `webdataset`, I select one tar file(webdataset shard) named `000000.tar` (18MB) to unpack and then repack into a new tarfile `example.tar` (15MB) in the shell (see commands in the followings). The repakced tarfile `example.tar` is smaller than the original tar file `000000.tar` by 3MB. I think these two tarfiles include totally the same things. And I have no idea why `000000.tar` is larger than `example.tar`.

This problem results in that tarfiles generated by `webdataset` occupy more disk space, which is inefficient. In fact, `webdataset` uses python built-in `tarfile` library to generate tarfile. There must be something different between python built-in `tarfile` library and the `tar` command in the shell. But I don't know how to figure it out.

- Supplementary:

I put these two files (`000000.tar` and `example.tar`) in [Google Drive](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1VD1tL9B7VyWq7aqx5xJnjfNmq1ueP_8c?usp=sharing). And I provide the command I used to generate `example.tar` in the followings.

```
(base) {22-09-01 2:25}vm:~/playground chenyaofo% ls -lha
total 18M
drwxrwxr-x  2 chenyaofo chenyaofo 4.0K Sep  1 02:25 .
drwxr-xr-x 39 chenyaofo chenyaofo 4.0K Sep  1 02:25 ..
-rw-rw-r--  1 chenyaofo chenyaofo  18M Sep  1 02:19 000000.tar
(base) {22-09-01 2:25}vm:~/playground chenyaofo% mkdir images
(base) {22-09-01 2:25}vm:~/playground chenyaofo% tar -xf 000000.tar -C images
(base) {22-09-01 2:26}vm:~/playground chenyaofo% tar -cf example.tar -C images .
(base) {22-09-01 2:26}vm:~/playground chenyaofo% ls -lha
total 33M
drwxrwxr-x  3 chenyaofo chenyaofo 4.0K Sep  1 02:26 .
drwxr-xr-x 39 chenyaofo chenyaofo 4.0K Sep  1 02:26 ..
-rw-rw-r--  1 chenyaofo chenyaofo  18M Sep  1 02:19 000000.tar
-rw-rw-r--  1 chenyaofo chenyaofo  15M Sep  1 02:26 example.tar
drwxrwxr-x  2 chenyaofo chenyaofo 160K Sep  1 02:26 images
```

In addition, I provide some system info and library info.
I use Ubuntu 22.04 `Linux vm 5.15.0-39-generic #42-Ubuntu SMP Thu Jun 9 23:42:32 UTC 2022 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux`. I use `python=3.9.13` and `webdataset=0.2.20` to generate webdataset shards. The version of tar command is `tar (GNU tar) 1.34`.

The code used to generate webdataset shards is available in [Github Gist](https://gist.github.com/chenyaofo/adca43b9163f7f76c9ce5d2b6cc21c5e).

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. It seems like this question is about how `tar` files work and what to expect from them. It is probably better on https://superuser.com. If you think something is wrong with the code, please read [ask] and [mre], and include the *relevant* code [*in the question itself*](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/376951) and not with a link.

Answer (score 2):

I maybe found the reason for the large tarfile size.

I found a similar question in [Stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69585800/what-is-the-fundamental-difference-between-tar-unix-and-tarfile-python).  In short,  python (>=3.8) built-in library uses `tarfile.PAX_FORMAT` as default to store tarfile. In constrast, the default format of `tar` command on Linux is `tarfile.GNU_FORMAT`. See more about these two formats [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/tarfile.html#tarfile.PAX_FORMAT) and [here](https://mort.coffee/home/tar/). `PAX_FORMAT` has a longer tar header than `GNU_FORMAT` and thus lead to large tarfile size.